# docker enterprise solution?

Tags: docker, puppet, artifactory, devops

I'm looking for a **paid docker solution** (**enterprise or some plugin**) which can take files from repositories in artifactory and create a docker image out of them. **Does such a plugin exist?**

I'm not sure if I should **have a pre-built 'base' image** and add to it the files from artifactory **or if I should build the entire image from scratch**.

**My solution:**
I use docker through puppet. I've set up puppet to call a docker script to create an image from artifactory files. My docker script just runs hello world for now since I'm just getting started with docker and learning its commands.
I see docker creating the image but I have no idea where it is stored. (maybe it doesn't store it?)

Is there a proper/standard way to do what I'm trying to accomplish here? Are there paid solutions that do this?
I'm not devops so please don't use devops jargon. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the information related to where the docker images are stored, you can execute the "docker info" command. Sudo if required.
Reference: https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/info/

Coming to placing the files  in your repository to Docker, what kind of files are they ?
Docker has the ability to take the files present in a directory and mount it inside an image virtually. This can be done by using the Docker run -v command.
Ref: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

You can also write a Dockerfile which can take a base image and mount the required folder/files.

Comment: I think the files in artifactory will be jar files (or source scala files which docker will need to compile to jars). Thanks for your reply! If I add the jars to the docker image w docker -v, do you think the original image should be stored in artifactory or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes. Once you write the content in the image, you will need to save the Docker image that is newly created. You can save by using the "Docker commit " command.
The Docker commit command accepts parameters such as the docker image you want to save and the name you want to save it with.

You need to check the docker process which is being run: docker ps
it will provide you with a unique Id related to the docker instance.

so use that along with the Docker commit command and save it.
Once you save it, you can push it to the DockerHub (or other private repositories) using the "Docker push " comman